# Converting lat,lon to x,y coordinates with pyproj

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, pyproj

I am trying to convert `lat,lon` to `x,y` coordinates in France, using the `pyproj` library and what I am doing is obviously wrong.

Here is some of my code:

```
import pyproj
import math

PROJ='+proj=utm +zone=31, +north +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs'

def LatLon_To_XY(Lat,Lon):
    p1=pyproj.Proj(PROJ,preserve_units=True)
    (x,y)=p1(Lat,Lon)
    return(x,y)


def XY_To_LatLon(x,y):
    p1=pyproj.Proj(PROJ,preserve_units=True)
    (lat,lon)=p1(x,y,inverse=True)
    return(lat,lon)

def distance(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    d1=x1-x2
    d2=y1-y2
    out=math.sqrt(d1*d1+d2*d2)
    return(out)
```

Problem is when I am validating this computing the distance between Paris and Toulouse, I get `816km` where the distance is supposed to be around `580km`.

I guess I have wrong parameters for the projection definition.

Here are the values displayed:

- For Paris `lat,lon (48.856614, 2.3522219)` and `x,y: 6253348.594037977 374425.11288885673`
- For Toulouse `lat,lon (43.604652, 1.444209)` and `x,y: 5453729.038474649 210744.18988320036`

Comment: thanks. so I can trust my computed x and y ?

Comment: made it into an answer...I do get some slighty different x & y when transforming in PostGIS, but the relative distance is the same

Comment: I think the Latitude and Longitude are swapped in your code, try with (lon,lat). Normally distances in UTM within a specific zone aren't distorted much more than 1 in 1000

Answer (score 3):

Nope, there's nothing wrong with your calculations; you are looking at projection distortions!

I´d suggest to use the built in [`Geod`](http://jswhit.github.io/pyproj/pyproj.Geod-class.html) class in `pyproj` for [geodetic computations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodesics_on_an_ellipsoid). e.g.

```
import pyproj
import math

P = pyproj.Proj(proj='utm', zone=31, ellps='WGS84', preserve_units=True)
G = pyproj.Geod(ellps='WGS84')

def LonLat_To_XY(Lon, Lat):
    return=P(Lon, Lat)    

def XY_To_LonLat(x,y):
    return P(x, y, inverse=True)    

def distance(Lat1, Lon1, Lat2, Lon2):
    return G.inv(Lon1, Lat1, Lon2, Lat2)[2]
```

or a framework that implements geodetic algebra, e.g. [vincenty](https://pypi.org/project/vincenty/), [GeoPy](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#module-geopy.distance)...